# JMeter - how to add strings as message body in post data?

Tags: servlets, jmeter

I have created a servlet that would accept post request from a mobile.
The strings are sent as streams to servlet, which would accept the the inputStream from the request.

How can I send those strings as post body message data in servlet? When I try to input these strings as values without names in parameters in JMeter's http request sampler, the servlet request.getInputStream() does not seems to get anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly try [HTTP Raw Request](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RawRequest) custom jmeter-plugin.

Comment: how do i install this plug in?

Comment: Why not to look across the project's content first? There is [Installation manual](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PluginInstall).

Comment: Here u can find jmeter plugins http://jmeter-plugins.org/...and to install just dump jar file in "apache-jmeter-2.11\lib\ext" than restart JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Since jmeter 2.6 you can do this with standard http sampler using post body mode:

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request